# gluPerspective parameters- what do they mean?

Tags: opengl, perspective, perspectivecamera

I wonder about the `gluPerspective` parameters.

In all examples I see `fovy` is set to around 45-60degrees
I've tried to set it to different values and the object just disappears 
what's the explanation for it?

The `aspect` value should always be the ratio? why would one change it?

`zNear, zFar` - once again the usual values are around 10 and 500+ what does it reflect?

Comment: It's explained [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml), there's even an example for the `aspect` parameter. It's the first Google hit. Could you be more specific as to what you didn't understand?

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg that is reference documentation, mostly useful to people who already know what they are doing.  I have been doing some work based on a file called Solar.c, and have had to infer a lot.  Just for example, is 100 a high or low value for zFar?  Those docs give no guidance on that . . . people asking here need more than reference docs, they need task-oriented stuff!

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The purpose of the 4 parameters is to define a **view frustum**, like this:

[image: perspective frustum]

where nothing outside of the frustum should be is visible on screen ( To accomplish this, the parameters are used to calculate a 4x4 matrix, which is then used to transform each vertex into the so-called clip space. There, testing if a vertex is inside the frustum or not is trivial )

**The field of view** parameter is basically the angle in between a plane passing through the camera position as well as the top of your screen & another plane passing through the camera position and the bottom of your screen. The bigger this angle is, the more you can see of the world - but at the same time, the objects you can see will become smaller.

To observe its influence, I'd suggest coding a simple app where you can gradually increase / decrease the fov via keypress - then render some spheres or other basic objects & see what happens as you change it.

**The aspect ratio** is your viewport's aspect ratio. ( In the graphic above, the viewport is located at the the near clipping plane ) Being able to define it at will makes sense, since your viewport's aspect ratio may vary.

**The zNear & zFar** values define the distance between the camera position & the near and far clipping planes, respectively. Nothing that's closer to the camera than zNear or farther away than zFar will be visible. Both values must be > 0, and obviously, zFar > zNear.
zFar should ideally be chosen so that everything you want to render is visible, but making it larger than necessary wastes depth buffer prescision & may lead to flickering effects, called z-fighting. Likewise, setting zNear too close to the camera may cause the same effect - in fact, having a reasonable zNear value is more important than zFar. If you want to know exactly why this happens, you should read some in-depth explanations, like [this one](http://www.sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/love_your_z_buffer.html) or [this one](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html)

Comment: perfect explanation ! Thanks

Comment: [gluPerspective](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml) function definition

Comment: You should note that the fovy (y-axis field of view) and the aspect ratio are used to calculate the left, right, top bottom of the frustrum matrix. https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GluPerspective_code

Comment: One can use Nate Robins' OpenGL tutors tutorial programs (https://user.xmission.com/~nate/tutors.html) to play with the parameters and visually see their effects.